# docker build failing on mount cache step

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, yarn-v2

Team,
I am trying to create my image with yarn bits and docker file is below on Mac OS.

```
Command> yarn -v
1.22.19

Command> node -v
v18.18.0
```

```
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim



RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsqlite3-dev python3 build-essential python3-pip && \
    yarn config set python /usr/bin/python3 && \
    # Needed for mkdocs-material
    pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.1.7


USER node


WORKDIR /app


ENV NODE_ENV production


COPY --chown=node:node yarn.lock package.json packages/backend/dist/skeleton.tar.gz ./
RUN tar xzf skeleton.tar.gz && rm skeleton.tar.gz

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid=1000 \
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production --network-timeout 300000


COPY --chown=node:node packages/backend/dist/bundle.tar.gz app-config*.yaml ./
RUN tar xzf bundle.tar.gz && rm bundle.tar.gz

CMD ["node", "packages/backend", "--config", "app-config.yaml", "--config", "app-config.production.yaml"]
```

any hint to error?.

error

```
 => CACHED [stage-0 2/8] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked     --mount=type=ca  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0 3/8] WORKDIR /app                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0 4/8] COPY --chown=node:node yarn.lock package.json packages/backend/dist/skeleton.ta  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0 5/8] RUN tar xzf skeleton.tar.gz && rm skeleton.tar.gz                                0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-0 6/8] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid  3.0s
------ 
 => ERROR [stage-0 6/8] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid  3.0s
------                                                                                                         
 > [stage-0 6/8] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/node/.cache/yarn,sharing=locked,uid=1000,gid=1000     yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production --network-timeout 300000:                                              
#0 0.404 yarn install v1.22.19                                                                                 
#0 0.521 [1/5] Validating package.json...                                                                      
#0 0.528 [2/5] Resolving packages...                                                                           
#0 1.255 [3/5] Fetching packages...
#0 1.271 warning Pattern ["app@link:packages/app"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/home/node/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-app-0.0.0/node_modules/app" as pattern ["app@0.0.0","app@0.0.0"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
#0 2.903 error @yarnpkg/parsers@3.0.0-rc.53: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=18.12.0". Got "16.20.2"
#0 2.914 error Found incompatible module.
#0 2.915 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production --network-timeout 300000]: exit code: 1
```